# How to run Python3 as root in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, resources, jupyter

I have quite a calculation intensive program running in jupyter notebook. On my centos machine I run the following code:

```
import resource
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_STACK, (2**29,-1))
```

and it works, on my mac machine I get this error:

```
ValueError: not allowed to raise maximum limit
```

I know this means that i have to run python as root in the jupyter notebook (which i have apparently done in my centos machine). But I how to instruct jupyter notebook or my mac to do this. Since i need to share this notebook with other mac users and they get the same error.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure of a good way to do this in python, but you could try `ulimit -s` in the shell where you're running jupyter.